# How can I know a GPU is off PCIE by using CUDA?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cuda, gpu, linux-device-driver

Now I need to monitor the GPU is working well on the ubuntu 18.04. Is there a way that kernel or CUDA provide to monitor GPU is plugged or not like the NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT in netlink which can get the USB hot plug event immediately by using epoll()?

Or where is the NVIDIA GPU device file in linux system, once the GPU is plugged in, for the reason that I think I can do this job by checking whether the device file is there or not periodically to do this job.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lspci` and search for a GPU with `grep`.

The former would list all devices connected via PCI on your machine, you would just have to figure out how the device identifies itself to or what address you expect it on. Presumably it would require some trial and error, I am not sure those addresses are hardware-defined, they might be shuffled on reboot?

Might be enough for a single GPU, might not for multiple. Just an idea.